# xpath for JSON not the same as XML

Tags: json, xml, xpath, marklogic

I'm trying to XPath into some JSON using the same technique I would use to access XML. Below are 2 equivalent structures with the same XPath applied.

```
let $json := xdmp:unquote('{
  "foo": {
    "bar": {
      "bas": "findme",
      "boo": "324"
    }
  }
}')

let $xml := <xml>
  <foo>
    <bar>
      <bas>findme</bas>
      <boo>324</boo>
    </bar>
  </foo>
</xml>

return (
    $xml//node()[./text() = "findme"], 
    $json//node()[./text() = "findme"]
)
```

I would expect the same result for both but I get the following:

**XML Result**

`<bas>findme</bas>`

**JSON result**

`{
  "bas": "findme", 
  "boo": "324"
}`

Why does this not produce the same result?

Comment: Your XML and JSON structures aren't equivalent.  I'm wondering if this XML is closer (though obviously the same XPath won't work): `<foo><bar bas="findme" boo="324"/></foo>`.  In any case, grtjn's answer is more helpful.

Comment: don't think that is closer because $json//bas works but not $json//@bas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MarkLogic the text property `bas` is a named text node, something that doesn't exist in XML space. It is designed such that something like `//bas` would work for both. Because of the named text node, the tree structure is different at deepest level:

```
element bas {
  text { "findme" }
},
element boo {
  text { "324" }
}
```

Versus:

```
object-node {
  text bas { "findme" },
  text boo { "324" }
}
```

Note: the latter is pseudo-code. Correct use of JSON constructors would be: `object-node { "bas": "findme", "boo": "324" }`.

There might be a way to get closer to what you are after by making use of `fn:name()` (`fn:local-name()` doesn't work here, by the way). Try something like:

```
let $json := xdmp:unquote('{
  "foo": {
    "bar": {
      "bas": "findme",
      "boo": "324"
    }
  }
}')

let $xml := <xml>
  <foo>
    <bar>
      <bas>findme</bas>
      <boo>324</boo>
    </bar>
  </foo>
</xml>

let $xml-text := $xml//text()[. = "findme"]
let $json-text := $json//text()[. = "findme"]
for $t in ($xml-text, $json-text)
return
  if (name($t) eq "") then
    $t/..
  else
    object-node { name($t): $t }
```

HTH!